# MVC4 pass model values from view (for-each) to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Hello dear i am trying to pass my model values from view to controller. when i am trying to do that i receive only null value in controller my view is given below
I also have used @html.hadden but still received only null value in contoller after button click. please someone help me and tell me the solution of this problem.

My VIEW IS THIS WHERE I AM TRYING TO PASS VALUE TO CONTOLLER:

```
@model IEnumerable<onlinebookstore.entityframwork.book>

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "ShopingCart", FormMethod.Post))
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <img src="@Url.Content(item.book_img)" alt="Image" width="170px"; height="230px" />
        <br />
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.book_name)
        <br />
        <label>Author:</label>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.author)
        <br />
        <label>Pk.</label>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.price, new { id = "price" })&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        @Html.ActionLink("For Detail..", "Detail", "Book", new { id = item.inventory_id }, null)
        <br />
        <input type="submit" class="btnreg" id="btnaddcart" value="Add to Basket"/>
        <br />
    }
}
```

My Controller where i am trying to receive values from view and here i received only null values

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToCart(book model)
{
    var cartitem = 
            db.shoping_cart_item
                .FirstOrDefault(u => u.inventory_id == model.inventory_id);

    if (cartitem == null && Session["userid"] != null)
    {
        cartitem = new shoping_cart_item();
        cartitem.inventory_id = model.inventory_id;
        cartitem.price = Convert.ToDecimal(model.price.ToString());
        db.shoping_cart_item.Add(cartitem);
    }
    return View();
}
```

My Model (BOOK)

```
public string inventory_id { get; set; }
public string book_name { get; set; }
public string author { get; set; }
public string book_type { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> no_book { get; set; }
public Nullable<decimal> price { get; set; }
public string book_img { get; set; }
public string book_description { get; set; }
```

Please help me how we will pass model value using for-each loop in view to Controller

Comment: Can you post your `onlinebookstore.entityframwork.book` model?

Comment: i have added my book model above now plz tell me why my book model value is not passing from view to controller

Answer (score 1):

You have no inputs for your form. You aren't submitting anything. Try @Html.TexboxFor() or some other helper.

Comment: I am just shown all the value here not receive any input from user therefore i used @html.DisplayFor instead of @Html.TextboxFor().

Comment: But your displayfors are inside a form. That won't ever submit anything.

Comment: So what will be the remedy of this problem where i can display my all values in view and on button click all the values of model will be pass on to controller.

Answer (score 0):

*So what will be the remedy of this problem where i can display my all values in view and on button click all the values of model will be pass on to controller.*

I think you are doing it wrong.

Your view is looping through the list of `onlinebookstore.entityframwork.book` to display the details AND one button for EACH of them inside one big form. When you submit that, all inputs that can be submitted will be posted (a collection of books at best). But on your controller, you are just receiving one instance of `onlinebookstore.entityframwork.book`

You might want to rethink your view by creating the loop first then inside it, have the `@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "ShopingCart", FormMethod.Post))` markup inside. This creates a form for each `onlinebookstore.entityframwork.book`. Just make the necessary adjustments for multi-form on a single page to work.